# Append string value to a variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to append a string value to a variable in shell script. The variable is read from a property file. But I am unable to append it to the string value. Please find below the code.

> Property file Location: /home/temp/script.properties

Contents of script.properties

```
log4j_path=/home/temp/config
```

Shell script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Add property file
file="/home/temp/script.properties"

#load property file
. $file

#Get log4J Path
export logger_path=$log4j_path/log4j.properties
echo $logger_path
```

> Expected output : /home/temp/config/log4j.properties

But I am not getting the above output. Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Regards,
Adarsh K S

Comment: It works for me. How do you run the script?

Comment: I am triggering the shell script from putty as ./<script_name>. I am not getting expected output.

Comment: Try adding `set -xv` after the first line of the script and running it again.

Comment: Did you mean after #!/bin/bash ?

Comment: I found the issue. There is a '\r' character at the end of the property which is being fetched. e.g, /home/temp/config\r.

Comment: Is there a way to remove all '\r' once we load the property file? Or do we need to perform tr-d \r for all the properties that I am reading from?

Comment: @Adarsh: Run `dos2unix <prop-file>`

Comment: dos2unix command is not found in my machine. I dont have permission to install it.

Comment: `dos2unix` was replaced by `fromdos` on some distributions.

Comment: `sed 's/\r$//' oldfile > newfile`

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands:

- > sudo chmod +x shell_script_name.sh
- > sudo ./shell_script_name.sh

This worked for me.

Comment: If you try without `sudo` you'll see it still works, so this is not the problem. It's bad practice to unnecessarily run things as root.